# getting to a working openwebrtc app on linux

Tags: linux, makefile, webrtc, glib, openwebrtc

I'm trying to get a simple native client to stream audio and video through the webrtc protocol using openwebrtc on a linux machine.

I've followed the build instructions here. https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc/wiki/Building-OpenWebRTC

There is no linux sample code so I've been trying to copy the OSX code bit by bit until I have something working. https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc-examples/blob/master/osx/Camera%20Test/Camera%20Test/AppDelegate.m

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <owr/owr.h>
#include <owr/owr_media_source.h>
#include <owr/owr_types.h>
#include <owr/owr_video_renderer.h>

#define SELF_VIEW_TAG "self-view"

static void got_sources(GList *sources, gpointer user_data) {
    g_assert(sources);

    // haven't actually gotten to showing video yet
    // the above line does not compile =(
}

int main(void) {
    printf("starting owr\n");
    owr_init(NULL);
    owr_run_in_background();

    owr_get_capture_sources(OWR_MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, got_sources, NULL);

    printf("exiting owr\n");
    owr_quit();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is I have compile errors with glib functions like g_assert or g_object_get.

```
> make
gcc webrtc-client.c -o webrtc-client -lopenwebrtc
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccd4VTU9.o: undefined reference to symbol 'g_object_get'
/opt/openwebrtc-0.3/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'webrtc-client' failed
```

These are the env variables I set in my Makefile

```
export PATH:=/opt/openwebrtc-0.3/bin:$(PATH)
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH:=/opt/openwebrtc-0.3/lib:$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
export GST_PLUGIN_PATH_1_0:=/opt/openwebrtc-0.3/lib/gstreamer-1.0/:$(GST_PLUGIN_PATH_1_0)
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH:=/opt/openwebrtc-0.3/lib/pkgconfig:$(PKG_CONFIG_PATH)
export CPATH:=/opt/openwebrtc-0.3/include:/opt/openwebrtc-0.3/include/glib-2.0:/opt/openwebrtc-0.3/lib/glib-2.0/include:$(CPATH)
export LIBRARY_PATH:=/opt/openwebrtc-0.3/lib:$(LIBRARY_PATH)
```

As part of the openwebrtc instalation cerbero installed glib under `/opt/openwebrtc-0.3/lib/`. I've also tried installing the apt package `libglib2.0-dev` and commenting out my PKG_CONFIG_PATH which did not work.

How do I get my build process to properly incorporate glib?

Answer (score 0):

g_object_get is part of gobject not glib.

I needed a `-lgobject-2.0` flag

damnit I hate myself

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12298427)

Comment: i needed `-lgobject-2.0`. that was my problem.